# iAds still show test ads

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I just released an app into the app store with iAds, however the app is still only showing the test ads. But the thing is it says "live" on itunesconnect. What is wrong with my ads?

Comment: Are you sure you're running the App Store version and not your development version?

Comment: Yes, I am I downloaded it from the app store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a developer preview of iOS 6 on your device?  That could always be a potential problem causing you to see iAd test ads.